AsReview problems
I am trying to use AsReview lab to screen papers for a meta-analysis. I followed the library's recommendations to open AsReview as follows (I am working on a Microsoft operating system):

open the command prompt
insert

C:\Users\samanha>python.exe -m asreview lab


press enter

However, when I press enter nothing happens, not even an error message pops up. Furthermore, I am unable to use the command prompt centre after that, meaning it won't let me write any more commands once I have pressed enter.
Do you have any suggestions on what might be the issue and how to solve it?
I tried to open AsReview, but it did not open in the browser as I expected.
I tried to follow the advice in another question ('Install AsReview via Python'), but this did not work either.

Install the ASReview software with Pip by running the following command in the CMD.exe (Windows) or Terminal (MacOS/Linux):
pip install asreview
Start the application with the following command (in CMD.exe or Terminal):
asreview lab
The ASReview LAB software starts in the browser.
